# Android push notifications to inactive devices

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, mobile-devices

I am testing my app deployment on a variety of devices...some of which are inactive phones (samsung/motoX).  When installing and launching the app on these devices I am getting pushIDs registered via googles FCM - but when I try to do push notifications to these inactive devices the notifications are never received.

The devices do have wifi enabled and get out to the internet/google, etc - but do the phones actually have to be active devices (sim card, on a carrier??) in order to receive push notifications?

What about iOS phones?  Do they have to be active as well?

Answer (score 0):

For FCM the push notifications, when identifying the device is inactive would not send them.  However they will send it once the inactive device becomes active again.